# My paypal link does not redirect to the paypal site

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I've migrate my magento from 1.5 to 1.7, but problem is coming in **http://dev.sinergiprima.co.id/wasis/checkout/cart/** page, when i click link paypal, it is not redirect to paypal site but it redirect again in **http://dev.sinergiprima.co.id/wasis/checkout/cart/**, Does any body can help me? I'm depressed to think of it, really need your helps guys..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding:

```
curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

to the write function in lib/Varien/Http/Adapter